# Question about proof of Kunneth theorem in Hatcher's book

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In the proof of the algebraic Kunneth formula, they proof first the special case where every boundary map in $C$ is zero. This implies $\partial(c \otimes d) = (-1)^{i}c\otimes \partial d $.

I don't understand how this implies $C \otimes_{R} C' = \oplus_i C_i \otimes_R C' $ and hence $H_n ( C_i \otimes_R C')= C_i\otimes_R H_{n-i}(C'))$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think he wants you to think of $C_i$ as a chain complex concentrated in degree i. Write this chain complex as $\underline C_i$ (so it has $C_i$ in degree i and 0s elsewhere and trivial differentials). Then $(\underline C_i\bigotimes C')_n=C_i\otimes C'_{n-i}$, so $(C\bigotimes C')_n=\oplus_i \;C_i\otimes C'_{n-i}=\bigoplus_i(\underline C_i\bigotimes C')_n$ and both chain complexes have the same underlying $R$-modules in each degree.

Now since $C$ has trivial differential the differential on $C\otimes C'$ is $\hat\partial_n=\oplus_i(\partial_i\otimes 1_{n-i}+(-1)^i1_i\otimes \partial'_{n-i})=\oplus_i\;(-1)^i1_i\otimes \partial'_{n-i}$. But $(-1)^i1_i\otimes \partial'$ is just the differential on $\underline C_i\otimes C'$. Hence $\hat \partial=\bigoplus_i(-1)^i1_i\otimes \partial'$, and the differentials on $C\bigotimes C'$  and $\bigoplus_i\; \underline C_i\bigotimes C'$ also agree. That is, they are the same chain complexes.

The statement for homology follows since each $C_i$ is free, and have $\underline C_i$ is a projective chain complex. The operation of tensoring with a projective module commutes with the operation of taking homology, so you get

$H_n(C'\bigotimes C)=H_n(\bigoplus_i\;\underline C_i\bigotimes C')\cong \oplus_i\;H_n(\underline C_i\bigotimes C')\cong \oplus_i\;  C_i\otimes H_{n-i}( C').$

I hope this may have been a little clearer (or at least a little more explicit).

Comment: Welp, this is the first time I've ever understood this strategy.

Comment: Does the homology commute with the tensor product of a projective module up to isomorphism and if so, is that isomorphism natural?

Comment: It should be clear how to get the isomorphism using the fact that $\partial(x\otimes x')=x\otimes \partial x'$.

Comment: okay so I think I understand why homology commutes with the tensor product but it is still not clear why instead of having $H_n$ we have $H_{n-i}$ after taking the tensor product

Comment: It's because (after the first isormorphisms) we are taking $H_n$ of the complex $\underline C_i\otimes C'$. That is the cycle group $ker(\partial:(\underline C_i)\otimes C')_n\rightarrow \underline C_i)\otimes C')_{n-1})$ mod the boundary group. But $(\underline C_i)\otimes C')_n=C_i\otimes C_{n-i}'$. The reindexing of the homology group comes about since the act of tensoring with $\underline C_i$ shifts the indexing on the complex $C'$.